# aws version 4 signature in C

Tags: c, linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use SQS on aws (on a linux box) using generic C. Not using any sdk (not that there is one for C). I can not find an example I can relate to. Sorry, I don't relate to these newfangled languages. I am proficient in Cobol, fortran, pascal and C. Not python, c++, c# or java. There are "steps" on amazon site, but honestly they expect proficiency on aws and an object oriented language. I just want to create my own https get command for accessing SQS/SNS, can anyone provide a 'C' snipet that creates a complete url with the version 4 signature? Or point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Somewhere in Amazon's documentation it tells you how to create the signatures. I wrote my own implementation for S3 in Java once (of course then I started using the SDK because it exists for Java and it's much easier).

Comment: Wow, I actually ask a question. A direct question and tag it correctly. Get down voted for that?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because, it is not clear what you are asking. You don't show your code, and you never state where (exactly) you are having trouble. Also see [Signature Version 4 Signing Process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). The [Amazon SDK's](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) probably have a language you can use given you are proficient in several languages.

Comment: @CarrieHarvard This question is off-topic because you are asking where to find an off-site resource.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that signing a request in C is  especially difficult... it is fundamentally just string concatenation, getting a date, and running some values through SHA256 with HMAC. The [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) may seem intimidating but it requires neither OO nor AWS domain-specific knowledge and the [test suite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html) gives you all the intermediate  values for several cases. I think the downvotes are reflective of incorrect assumptions about what this question asks.

Comment: I got this working, primarily using information from a comment that has since been deleted and continuing from there. Part of the problem lies in incorrect AWS documentation, but looking at samples can (and did) clear this up. The other part lies in inexperience, until you have worked with AWS/signing it is hard to distinguish between outdated and newer signing methods, they are not (always) clearly marked on AWS and especially not marked well on outside resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

If you're proficient with any programming language, you should be able to understand all of that code. It's just string operations and some hashing for which you'll have to use another library. There's also lots of comments to help you with the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libcurl for the call:

Use CURLOPT_AWS_SIGV4 argument for the signature https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_AWS_SIGV4.html

You can take a look at CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION if you want to store the result into a variable: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html

And for debugging purpose CURLOPT_VERBOSE can be useful too: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html

Note that you need a version of libcurl superior to 7.75.